# How to accept multiple arguments in system() in Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to implement a system() using fork() and execl(). I am unable to accept multiple arguments like ls -l and ps -a1. The code works for arguments like ls and ps. I am unable to do it. It is not allowed to change the arguments and return type of my_system(). I am a beginner. Thanks:)

```
int my_system(const char *command)
{
    int ret = 0;

    ret = execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *)NULL);
    if (ret == -1)
        error(1, 0, "error occcured in the execl() system call\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t ret;
    char *command;
    int ret_system;
    int wstatus;

    if (argc < 2)
        error(1, 0, "Too few arguments\n");
    printf("The number of arguments are: %d", argc);
    command =  argv[1];
    printf("The pid of the parent-process is :%d\n", getpid());
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        error(1, 0, "error in creating the sub-process\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("The pid of the child- process is :%d\n", getpid());
        ret_system = my_system(command);
    } else {
        ret = waitpid(-1, &wstatus, 0);
        printf("The pid of the child that has terminated is %d and the status of exit is %d\n", ret, wstatus);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why exec shell in my system. Why not exec "command"? Some exec variations allow arguments. Also, you may consider moving fork to my_system.

Comment: Your program gets the arguments of the command to run as separate arguments.  You need to concatenate them together yourself.

Comment: If you are running your program like `./foo ls -l`, the program will see 3 arguments (including the program name itself in `argv[0]`). You may need to run the program with the command quoted as a single argument like `./foo "ls -l"`. Then the program will see 2 arguments - the program name in `argv[0]` and the command to be executed in `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 3 changes :

```
int my_system(char *argv[])
...
    ret = execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
...
        ret_system = my_system(argv);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int my_system(const char *command)
{
    int ret = 0;

    ret = execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *)NULL);
    if (ret == -1)
        error(1, 0, "error occcured in the execl() system call\n");
    return 0;
}

char *get_command(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    static char command[size];

    strcpy(command, argv[1]);
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        strcat(command, " ");
        strcat(command, argv[i]);
    }
    return command;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t ret;
    int ret_system;
    int i = 0;
    int wstatus;
    char *command;

    if (argc < 2)
        error(1, 0, "Too few arguments\n");
    printf("The pid of the parent-process is :%d\n", getpid());
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        error(1, 0, "error in creating the sub-process\n");
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        printf("The pid of the child- process is :%d\n", getpid());
        command = get_command(argc, argv);
        ret_system = my_system(command);
    } else {
        ret = waitpid(-1, &wstatus, 0);
        printf("The pid of the child that has terminated is %d and the status of exit is %d\n", ret, wstatus);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kjohri .Could you please tell me the movement of fork() to my_system function. It would be helpful if you explain. Thanks a lot:).

Comment: @dbush  Thanks a lot.